# interface with the computer in a motor vehicle using the .NET framework

Tags: .net, interface, robotics

Is there a way to communicate with the ECU or engine computer of a car to do things like read ODB/CAN codes similar to a handheld code scanner you would get at the local auto parts store?

Ideally a Microsoft .NET API or COM interface is what I am personally looking for, but I can see an API like that coming in other strange and legacy flavors.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just plug USB in to your car and expect it to work, there will be some kind of hardware between the two. That peice of hardware will come with a SDK to write software that uses it.

What you need to do is choose a piece of hardware to buy that comes with a SDK that works in .NET (in a fully managed class or, more likely, as a set of C interfaces you will need to P/Invoke to).

Answer (score 0):

use a micro controller to connect between car hardware and .net IDE and communicate between both.
like arduino micro controller

and use serial port to usb connections